# Is there a way to redirect from 127.0.0.1/8000 to Django admin site?

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin, django-urls

I changed page 127.0.0.1/8000 for an index page, now what I am interested to do is to put a button and that this button redirects me to the admin site of my app. I still do not know much about Django's urls and views, I would appreciate any tip or answer to help me with my problem.

Comment: If you are using front end and back end separate then add this in your urls.py `(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls) ),`. And onclick call that url.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare Thanks for the link below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Generally, the admin page is located at `127.0.0.1:8000/admin`. You can have a link such as `<a class="button" href="/admin"><button type="button">Go To Admin Site</button></a>`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :-

You can use the URL resolver in your template.
examples:-

```
{% url 'admin:index' %}

{% url 'admin:add' %}

{% url 'admin:change' choice.id %}

{% url 'admin:choice_changelist' %}
```

You can  refer this [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)